# Как перменную $scope изменять соответственно к $http status?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ng-repeat

У меня есть пустой массив `$scope.todos = [];`

```
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/tasks'
  }).then(function successCallback(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (status == 204){
        console.log('status ='+ status);
      }
      if(status == 200){
        var seen = [];
        var jsonResp = JSON.stringify(data, function(key, val) {
          if (typeof val == "object") {
            if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0)
              return
              seen.push(val)
            }
          return val;
        });
        console.log(jsonResp);
        console.log(data);
        $scope.todos = jsonResp;
      }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
  });
```

Вообще нужно,чтоб при ответе 200 `jsonResp` выглядит так :`[{},{}]`,но в перменная `$scope.todos` не равна `jsonResp` 
И сообственно ничего не выводит

`<div class="task_block col-md-3 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="todo in todos">`

Comment: зачем вы превращаете данные в json строку, а потом пытаетесь использовать строку как массив вот здесь: `ng-repeat="todo in todos"`

Comment: Вы имеете в виду,что не надо этого?Ну типо просто $scope.todos = data;?

Comment: да, я не понимаю, чего вы хотите добиться сериализацией

Comment: Ну да забейте,просто у меня работает,если вручную ввести   $scope.todos = [ {text: "go for a walk",dt: new Date(),done: true,priority: "low" }]; ,потому подумал,что можно добиться такого же результата,но понимаете,я не могу это сделать что з,что без сериализации